# Iterating over list elements the corresponding values

Tags: r

I have developed a function that produces a variance test or summary on the residuals of a linear model. For the variance test, it takes columns and specific values to input. However, I am finding that when I loop this function on my list of linear models, I am not getting the output I want. I believe the corresponding values are not matching the columns.

For example:

```
perTest_nl <- function(model, ...) {
  pr <- list(...)
    if (is(pr[[1]],'list') == TRUE) {
      if (length(pr[[1]]) != 3) {
        stop('You need three parameters, i.e. list("data", "column", "value")')
      } else {
        dataset <- pr[[1]][[1]] 
        column <- pr[[1]][[2]]
        value <- pr[[1]][[3]]
        #print(paste(dataset %>% data.frame(), column, value))
        dataset <- dataset %>% data.frame()
        variance_test <-
            var.test(residuals(model)[dataset[,column] > value], residuals(model)[dataset[,column] < value])
        return(variance_test)
      }
    } else {
      sumry <-
        parse(text = "summary(lm(sqrt(abs(residuals(model))) ~ fitted(model)))")
      
      if (pr[[1]] == 'summary') {
        model_diagnostic <-
          #model %>%
            eval(sumry)$coefficients %>%
              data.frame() %>%
              .[2, ] %>%
              add_column(
                F_statistic = eval(sumry)$fstatistic[1],
                p_value = 1 - pf(
                  eval(sumry)$fstatistic[[1]],
                  eval(sumry)$fstatistic[[2]],
                  eval(sumry)$fstatistic[[3]]
                ),
                df = eval(sumry)$fstatistic[[3]],
                RSE = eval(sumry)$sigma
              ) %>% `colnames<-`(
                c(
                  'Estimate',
                  'Std.Error',
                  't.value',
                  'Pr(>|t|)',
                  'F.statistic',
                  'P.value',
                  'df',
                  'RSE'
                )
              )
        return(model_diagnostic)
      } 
      
    }
    
    
  }  

library(faraway)
data(savings)

predictors <- c("pop15", "pop75", "dpi", "ddpi")
scan_values <- list(pop15 = 35, pop75 = 2.5, dpi = 2000, ddpi = 7)

lm1 <- lm(sr ~ pop15 +pop75+dpi, savings)
lm2 <- lm(sr ~ pop15 +pop75+dpi+ddpi, savings)
lmod1<- list(lm1, lm2)

val_list <- c()
for(i in predictors){
    val_list[[i]]<-map(lmod1, function(x)perTest_nl(x, list(savings, i, scan_values)))
}
```

The last result produces:

```
$ddpi[[2]]

    F test to compare two variances

data:  residuals(model)[dataset[, column] > value] and residuals(model)[dataset[, column] < value]
F = 0.96324, num df = 9, denom df = 39, p-value = 0.9685
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3913731 3.3807360
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.9632433
```

However, when I test the function manually, I get:

```
> perTest_nl(lmod1[[2]], list(savings, 'ddpi', 7))

    F test to compare two variances

data:  residuals(model)[dataset[, column] > value] and residuals(model)[dataset[, column] < value]
F = 0.7781, num df = 5, denom df = 43, p-value = 0.8581
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2702939 4.7962941
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.7780994
```

I also get the right result when I put:

```
map(lmod1, function(x)perTest_nl(x, list(savings, names(scan_values) %>% last(), scan_values %>% last())))
```

So something is not matching when iterating in the loop
How do I get the same output as the manual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to correctly get the looping logic by storing `scan_values` and the `predictors` as lists, then by using `mapply` to iterate over the lists of the same size within the function.

For example:

```
scan_val <- cbind(names(scan_values), scan_values ) %>% data.frame()

mapply(function(x, y)map(lmod1, function(z)perTest_nl(z,list(savings, x, y))), b$V1, b$scan_values, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Output:

```
$ddpi
$ddpi[[1]]

    F test to compare two variances

data:  residuals(model)[dataset[, column] > value] and residuals(model)[dataset[, column] < value]
F = 0.51833, num df = 5, denom df = 43, p-value = 0.4781
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1800548 3.1950245
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.5183266 


$ddpi[[2]]

    F test to compare two variances

data:  residuals(model)[dataset[, column] > value] and residuals(model)[dataset[, column] < value]
F = 0.7781, num df = 5, denom df = 43, p-value = 0.8581
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2702939 4.7962941
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.7780994
```